# Imageloader for displaying the Image in an activity

Tags: java, android, json

**Check this URL I am USING** :: `http://54.218.73.244:7006/DescriptionSortedRating/`

Images will append with relative path from JSON out put using `restaurantIMAGE`

**EX::**

```
http://54.218.73.244:7006/CopperChimney1.jpg
```

I am using `restaurantIMAGE` from JSON

```
{
  "restaurants": [
    {
      "restaurantID": 4,
      "restaurantNAME": "CopperChimney1",
      "restaurantIMAGE": "MarkBoulevard1.jpg",
      "restaurantDISTANCE": 15,
      "restaurantTYPE": "Indian",
      "restaurantRATING": 1,
      "restaurantPrice": 11,
      "restaurantTime": "9am t0 8pm"
    },
    {
      "restaurantID": 1,
      "restaurantNAME": "CopperChimney",
      "restaurantIMAGE": "CopperChimney.png",
      "restaurantDISTANCE": 5,
      "restaurantTYPE": "Indian",
      "restaurantRATING": 3,
      "restaurantPrice": 20,
      "restaurantTime": "8pm to 11pm"
    },
```

### I am USING IMAGE LOADER

**ImageLoader.java**

```
    public class ImageLoader {

        MemoryCache memoryCache = new MemoryCache();
        FileCache fileCache;
        private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews = Collections
                .synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());
        ExecutorService executorService;
        // Handler to display images in UI thread
        Handler handler = new Handler();

        public ImageLoader(Context context) {
            fileCache = new FileCache(context);
            executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
        }

        final int stub_id = R.drawable.temp_img;

        public void DisplayImage(String url, ImageView imageView) {
            imageViews.put(imageView, url);
            Bitmap bitmap = memoryCache.get(url);
            if (bitmap != null)
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            else {
                queuePhoto(url, imageView);
                imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
            }
        }

        private void queuePhoto(String url, ImageView imageView) {
            PhotoToLoad p = new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
            executorService.submit(new PhotosLoader(p));
        }

        private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
            File f = fileCache.getFile(url);

            Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
            if (b != null)
                return b;

            // Download Images from the Internet
            try {
                Bitmap bitmap = null;
                URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) imageUrl
                        .openConnection();
                conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
                conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
                conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
                InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
                OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
                Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
                os.close();
                conn.disconnect();
                bitmap = decodeFile(f);
                return bitmap;
            } catch (Throwable ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                if (ex instanceof OutOfMemoryError)
                    memoryCache.clear();
                return null;
            }
        }

        // Decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
        private Bitmap decodeFile(File f) {
            try {
                // Decode image size
                BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                FileInputStream stream1 = new FileInputStream(f);
                BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream1, null, o);
                stream1.close();

                // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
                // Recommended Size 512
                final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;
                int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
                int scale = 1;
                while (true) {
                    if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE
                            || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE)
                        break;
                    width_tmp /= 2;
                    height_tmp /= 2;
                    scale *= 2;
                }

                // Decode with inSampleSize
                BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                o2.inSampleSize = scale;
                FileInputStream stream2 = new FileInputStream(f);
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream2, null, o2);
                stream2.close();
                return bitmap;
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        // Task for the queue
        private class PhotoToLoad {
            public String url;
            public ImageView imageView;

            public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i) {
                url = u;
                imageView = i;
            }
        }

        class PhotosLoader implements Runnable {
            PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;

            PhotosLoader(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad) {
                this.photoToLoad = photoToLoad;
            }

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                        return;
                    Bitmap bmp = getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
                    memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
                    if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                        return;
                    BitmapDisplayer bd = new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad);
                    handler.post(bd);
                } catch (Throwable th) {
                    th.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        boolean imageViewReused(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad) {
            String tag = imageViews.get(photoToLoad.imageView);
            if (tag == null || !tag.equals(photoToLoad.url))
                return true;
            return false;
        }

        // Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
        class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable {
            Bitmap bitmap;
            PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;

            public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, PhotoToLoad p) {
                bitmap = b;
                photoToLoad = p;
            }

            public void run() {
                if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                    return;
                if (bitmap != null)
                    photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                else
                    photoToLoad.imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
            }
        }

        public void clearCache() {
            memoryCache.clear();
            fileCache.clear();
        }

    }
```

---

### Utils,FileCache,MemoryCache java files are also there

**RestaurantDescPhotos.java**

```
public class RestaurantDescPhotos extends Activity {
    // url to make request

    private static String url = "http://54.218.73.244:7006/DescriptionSortedRating/";

    String restaurant_name, cc_res;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    JSONObject jsonObject;
    JSONArray first_array;
    ImageLoader imageLoader;
    TextView textView;
    TextView text;

    private SparseArray<String> imagesMap = new SparseArray<String>();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list_of_images = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.restaurant_desc_photos);

        imageLoader=new  ImageLoader(RestaurantDescPhotos.this);

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(RestaurantDescPhotos.this);
        new ParsingAsync().execute();
    }

    private class ParsingAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(RestaurantDescPhotos.this, "",
                    "Please Wait", true, false);

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String _response = null;
            try {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                httpclient.getParams().setParameter(
                        CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION,
                        HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);



                HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
                HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
                _response = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);

                jsonObject = new JSONObject(_response);
                first_array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("restaurants");

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            progressDialog.dismiss();

            // TextView timedisplay=(TextView)
            // findViewById(R.id.RestaurantTimeID);

            for (int i = 0; i < first_array.length(); i++) {
                try {
                    JSONObject detail_obj = first_array.getJSONObject(i);

                    HashMap<String, String> map_for_images = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    int id = detail_obj.getInt("_id");
                    String IMAGES = "http://54.218.73.244:7006/"+detail_obj.getString("restaurantIMAGE");

                    map_for_images.put("Starters", IMAGES);

                    list_of_images.add(map_for_images);


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }


            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.DISP_IMG);

            imageLoader.DisplayImage(url, imageView);


        }
    }
}
```

### I am facing the problems in setting the images onto image view using image loader

**There is some problem in `RestaurantDescPhotos.java` ... I am not able to figure it out**

***Any Ideas***

Comment: In your Json response you are getting the image name only not exact path where its located. You need to change your json response with the image path. You need to define the Whole path of your image not name then only it will work.

Comment: Do you get any error ?

Comment: If you observe in the class RestaurantDescPhotos.java ....... i have tried to append the path in the line ..........................String IMAGES = "http://54.218.73.244:7006/" ............ combining that with image name  it becomes complete path ... hope i am clear

Comment: Does this loads the image ? Have your tried to check this url in browser? Because as its local i can not check it.

Comment: this link for example .......... http://54.218.73.244:7006/CopperChimney1.jpg

Comment: the image is obtained in browser ........ but im not sure whether i am putting in the right place for appending ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `url` content is not a valid image url:

```
imageLoader.DisplayImage(url, imageView);
```

I tried a fixed image url, and image is loaded successfully:

```
String path = "http://54.218.73.244:7006/CopperChimney1.jpg";
imageLoader.DisplayImage(path, imageView);
```

Comment: What if there is array of these URL's .... how to populate the imageview ... any ideas ?

Comment: You need to have multiple image views in a list or a grid.